# TypeScript lightweight scripting support with ESLint and Prettier

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, prettier, ts-node

TypeScript/ESLint/Prettier have become my favorite tools for all kind of tasks.
However, I am still struggling with small Nodejs-scripts that are just a few dozens lines of code.
To write a small Nodejs-script with a comfortable IDE-experience, I need to:

- Create a package.json
- Configure tsconfig (strict compilation)
- Configure ESLint
- Configure Prettier
- Compile to JavaScript if I care about startup performance (see below)

This is quite a lot of ceremony for small scripts. I have scripts where those configuration files are larger than the actual code.
JavaScript-compilation is especially annoying if you just want to make a small tweak and then re-run the script.

In theory, there exists `ts-node` to solve those issues.
However, I struggle with `ts-node` because of the following reasons:

- Slow startup performance (>2 seconds for many scripts)
- Lacks good typechecking unless you supply additional configuration
- Lacks a good IDE-experience unless you configure all the above-mentioned stuff

Do you have any suggestions on how to quickly write small scripts, without deteriorating the ESLint/Prettier-experience?

Answer (score 0):

My solution in part to this was to write an eslint config that inspects `package.json` and auto configs itself to what ever tools my project is using

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/eslint-config-auto

For the other bits I would use a simple boilier plate project as a starting point.

Comment: Self-inspecting might be a great solution. However, I am looking for something that is specifically for Nodejs-CLI-scripts. Therefore, I need neither Babel nor React for those tasks.

Comment: They only load if needed by the project, maybe fork the project to your own needs

Comment: Anyway I'm interested to see what other answer come up to this, so will be following along

Comment: I am sorry, it seems that I misunderstood your tool. So ESLint and Prettier might be solved, the other parts are tsconfig and JavaScript compilation.

Comment: Maybe checkout kcd-scripts for the other bits

Comment: Also this may help https://link.medium.com/oM0ZGUJW79

Comment: A boilerplate is not exactly the thing that I am looking for, because I do not want to copy a template. Instead, I am looking for a CLI-template that will continously update itself without managing everything on my own. Something like "create-react-app", but less bloated and less opinionated.

Comment: I think this is the closest thing to what your after https://kentcdodds.com/blog/tools-without-config

Answer (score 0):

Your TypeScript scripts should use the same ESLint config as your code-base. Don't use TypeScript scripts for non-TypeScript projects.

For making the code less verbose, look into: https://github.com/google/zx